Is it possible to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^4 \sqrt{t^2-25}} dt $
This question was in my Calc 2 final and I was stumped with these limits. First, I'm confused since $f(t)$ isn't defined for $-5 \leq t \leq 5$. My teacher suggested I treat it as an improper integral, but I'm not sure that works out.
What I tried was to find the antiderivative first by trig substitution:
Consider $\int\frac{1}{t^4 \sqrt{t^2-25}} dt$
If $\sqrt{t^2-25}=5\tan \theta$, $t=5\sec\theta$ and $dt=\sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta$
We have $\int\frac{5\sec \theta \tan \theta}{(5\sec \theta)^4 5 \sec \theta} d\theta = \frac{1}{5^4}\ \int\frac{1}{\sec^3 \theta} d \theta$
With $u$-sub and trig identities, we get
$=\frac{1}{5^4}\ [\sin \theta - \frac{1}{3}\sin^3 \theta] $
In terms of $t$:
$= \frac{1}{5^4}\ [ \frac{\sqrt{t^2-25}}{t}\ - \frac{1}{3}\ (\frac{\sqrt{t^2-25}}{t}\ )^3 ]$
Back to our integral:
$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^4 \sqrt{t^2-25}} dt = \frac{1}{5^4}\ [ \frac{\sqrt{t^2-25}}{t}\ - \frac{1}{3}\ (\frac{\sqrt{t^2-25}}{t}\ )^3 ]^1_0 $
And of course I run into the same issue of having a division by zero. If I take the limit, then I find it diverges.
Looking forward to comments! Please let me know if I'm making mistakes or conceptual errors.
Thanks!

I agree with your first line: there is no meaningful way for this to be treated as an improper integral on that domain, and I'm surprised your instructor didn't spot an error so obvious especially when pointed out. The function isn't defined anywhere within the domain of integration. Maybe they wanted $25-t^2$ instead?

If you don't allow complex numbers, the integral doesn't exist because the integrand is undefined on the interval in question.  If you do allow complex numbers, it is an improper integral that diverges because the integrand goes to (complex) $\infty$ like $1/x^4$ as $x \to 0$.

I suggest that you print out this webpage and show it to your teacher.
